# MySQL group users notifications by date and combine content

Tags: mysql, database

My notification table:

[image]

For example, it has 3 records:

[image]

I want to group and combine first two records (not third) by the same content_type if date_added is hour interval. Something like

ID sender_id user_id type content content_type text date_added locale

8459 - 2 - 0 - friends - 122551;12517 - Will see - null - 2021-03-16 07:40:27 - null

8455 - 2 - 0 - friends - 122550 - Watched - null - 2021-03-16 07:28:00 - null

Is it possible in MySQL? Or should i re-design my table structure? Any thoughts will be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Grouping by "hour interval" is not well defined. What happens for e.g. these `07:00:00`, `07:45:00`, `08:30:00`? Do all of them go in the same group? If not - which ones get grouped?

Comment: Yeah, all 3 should be grouped. If the new notification has the time interval of 1 hour with the last notification of this type, they should be grouped. 
First notifictation - 07:00
Second - 07:45 -45 min interval with the latest notification - grouped
Third - 08:30 - 45min interval with the latest notification - grouped

Comment: So there will be two groups and the 2-nd notification will be in both?

Comment: In your example it will be one group if they all have the same content_type. My goal is display in feed:
userX added 3 items to Will see - 30 min ago. If he added one more item, there should be: userX added 4 items to Will see - now. Then if he will add more items in 2 hours, it will be two groups

Comment: It is possible to do this in MySQL, but it becomes a mess. It will probably be easier to do the grouping in the application.

Comment: I can’t do this in app because I also need to limit these records for each content_type